# Open with Rosetta not available

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I've just downloaded Visual Studio Code ( 1.51.1 ) on an Apple Silicon MBP. I downloaded the Intel version (the ARM version is still in dev I think) assuming that I would have to right click and select 'Open with Rosetta 2' like you can with Terminal for example.

[image: ability to open in rosetta]

However it just opens without question without the option even being available to select - is Apple doing this automatically knowing that it's an Intel version or is something else going on?

Comment: Curious which version of code you ended up with, there are quite a few versions and builds out there and lots of places to download software.

Comment: @bmike https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ downloaded from there. This is from Code > About
Version: 1.51.1
Commit: e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
Date: 2020-11-11T01:11:34.018Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.1.0

Comment: Perfect - I assume you have your answer on what's going on now... Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intel-only binaries automatically open with Rosetta 2, there is no other way to run them. The "Open using Rosetta" flag is only relevant for universal binaries (which contain both Intel and ARM code) to force them to open with Rosetta (e.g. if they require plugins only available as Intel binaries).

From [If you need to install Rosetta on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861)

> The Info window for universal apps includes the setting “Open using Rosetta.” It enables email apps, web browsers, and other apps to use add-ons that haven't been updated to support Apple silicon. If an app doesn't recognize a plug-in, extension, or other add-on, quit the app, select this setting, and try again.